# unexpected identifier Why doesn't it work?

Tags: javascript

I haven't written in JS for a long time and now I don't understand what's the problem at all?

```
<span>hey</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
    let span = document.querySelector("span");
    
    class A
        {
            function myf(_width, _height)
            {
                span.style.width = _width;
                span.style.height = _height;
                console.log("Work!");
            }
        }
    
</script>
```

unexpected identifier

Comment: `function myf(_width, _height)` is not valid syntax inside a `class` body: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Answer (score 0):

This might be obvious but this is an example of your class:

```js
let span = document.querySelector("span");

class A {
  myf(_width, _height) {
    console.log(span.style.width);
    span.style.width = _width;
    span.style.height = _height;
    console.log("Work!");
    console.log(span.style.width);
  }
}
let athing = new A();
athing.myf("10em", "3em");
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px lime;
}
```

```html
<span>hey</span>
```

If you really want you can call it a function deliberately but seems slightly odd to me:

```js
let span = document.querySelector("span");

class A {
   myf = function(_width, _height) {
    console.log(span.style.width);
    span.style.width = _width;
    span.style.height = _height;
    console.log("Work!");
    console.log(span.style.width);
  }
}
let athing = new A();
athing.myf("10em", "3em");
```

```css
span {
  display: block;
  border: solid 1px lime;
}
```

```html
<span>hey</span>
```